# Problema com função de busca e inserção

Tags: c, ponteiro, algoritmo-de-busca

Tentei escrever o código abaixo por curiosidade. Por algum motivo, mesmo após fazer as funções de *inserção* e *verificação* (verifica se um valor existe dentro do vetor), *o retorno é de que não existe o valor dentro do vetor*. É como se não tivesse atualizando os dados!

acabei conseguindo fazer ele funcionar, mas ainda queria saber se existe uma maneira melhor de fazer o codigo abaixo.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct vet{
    int tam;
    int key[10];
    char content[10][60];
};
typedef struct vet vetor;
void insert(vetor *s, int ind, char cnt[]){
    int i;
    s->key[s->tam] = ind;
    strcpy(s->content[s->tam], cnt);
    s->tam++;
}
int search(vetor s, int ind){
    int i, k;
    for(i = 0; i < s.tam; i++){
        if (s.key[i] == ind)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    vetor s1;
    s1.tam = 0;
    insert(&s1, 11, "acre");
    if (search(s1, 11))
        printf("found\n");
    else
        printf("not found\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analisando seu código, você errou por conta de **referências** perdidas e **ponteiros**. Explico:

Quando você **passar uma variável para a função**, você passará **uma cópia do valor** e não a variável em si. Toda alteração feita, portanto, fica dentro do **escopo** dessa nova variável - que é a função. Então, se você não retornar os valores, você os perde. **Por este motivo é que existem ponteiros e referências!**

Se você **passar o endereço da variável** que quer modificar (por meio do `&`), você **altera a variável e não mais uma cópia**. Aí ela fica armazenada num ponteiro e não numa variável comum. **Exemplo simples**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mudando_x(int *referencia){

    *referencia = 2;

}

int main (void) {

    int x = 1;

    mudando_x( &x );

    printf("O valor de X é %d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

O resultado disso é

```
$ O valor de X é 2
```

**Já para `struct`**, ao invés de usar o `.` e o `*`, você usa `->` no lugar de `.` e esquece do `*` no acesso. Na definição da função você sempre vai usar o `*`. Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct estrutura {
    int id;
    };

typedef struct estrutura Estrutura;

void mudando_x(Estrutura *referencia){

    referencia->id = 2;

}

int main (void) {

    Estrutura x;

    x.id = 1;

    mudando_x( &x );

    printf("O valor de X é %d", x.id);

    return 0;
}
```

O resultado disso é

```
$ O valor de X é 2
```

Assim, você precisa fazer *algumas* modificações. E se não ficou muito claro a explicação acima, vai compreender melhor com o seu código arrumado. Veja:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct vet{

    int tam;
    int key[10];
    char content[10][60];

};

typedef struct vet vetor;

void insert(vetor *s, int ind, char cnt[]){

    int i;

    s->key[s->tam] = ind;

    for(i = 0; i < 60; i++){

        s->content[s->tam][i] = cnt[i];

        if (cnt[i] == '\0') break;

    }

    s->tam++;

}

int search(vetor *s, int ind){

    int i;

    printf( "search - ind: %d\n", ind );
    printf( "search - s.tam: %d\n", s->tam );

    for(i = 0; i < s->tam; i++) {

        printf( "search - i: %d\n", i );
        printf( "search - s.key[i]: %d\n", s->key[i] );

        if (s->key[i] == ind)
            return 1;

    }

    return 0;

}

int main(){

    vetor s1;
    s1.tam = 0;

    insert(&s1, 11, "acre");

    if (search(&s1, 11)) printf("found\n");
    else printf("not found\n");

    return 0;

}
```